# How to Copy a folder to another folder by finding matching String contained in each folder name using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am new to this, so hopefully I am getting this right.  I have done a fair amount of research over the past couple days that I have been struggling with this code, and I just can't get it to do what I want.

I have a source directory containing several directories.  I have a destination Directory containing several directories.  The names of the directories all have a four digit number within them, but not in the same location of the name.  I want to find that number in the name of each of the source directories, and use that number to find the directories in the destination directory with the same numbers in their name.  Once I find a matching destination directory, move the source directory with say, folder name 33-fit-1234, into the destination directory with the matching number ie. 33-F-1234.  I am currently doing the move by Copying then deleting the source.

Source Folder names can be 33-ait-1743A, or 33-xx-4533 UNKNOWN, etc.
Destination Folder names are all in the format: 33-x-####, with some having a single letter suffix, such as A, B, etc.

Here is the code:

```
$sourceDirectory = "D:\Test Source"
$destinationDirectory = "D:\Test Dest"

$sourceFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDirectory -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$destinationFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationDirectory -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$matchesInBoth = $sourceFolders -match "\d{4}" | ?{$_ -eq $_}
$matchesInBoth | ForEach-Object{
    $sourcePath = (Join-Path $sourceDirectory $_)
    Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath -Destination 
$destinationDirectory\$matchesInBoth\$_ -Recurse -whatif
    Remove-Item $sourcePath -Force -Recurse -WhatIf 
}
```

It's close, the output I get is:

```
What if: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: D:\Test 
Source\33-FV-1414 Destination: D:\Test Dest\33-FIT-1414 33-FIT-1576 33-FIT- 
1654A 33-fred-1234 unknown 33-FSL-1649 33-FV-1414 33-FV-1654 33-FV-1882 
33-H-1657 33-H-1814 33-H-1924\33-FV-1414".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "D:\Test 
Source\33-FV-1414".
```

The problem is:
I end up copying the source folder into a new folder named after all the folder names in my source directory.

I have also tried this code with no results:

```
$sourceDirectory = "D:\Test Source"
$destinationDirectory = "D:\Test Dest"

$sourceFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDirectory -Directory | Select-    Object -ExpandProperty BaseName | Select-String "\d{4}"
$destinationFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationDirectory -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName

$matchesInBoth = $destinationFolders | ?{$_ -contains $sourceFolders}
$matchesInBoth | ForEach-Object{
$sourcePath = (Join-Path $sourceDirectory $_)
Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath -Destination $destinationDirectory\$matchesInBoth\$_ -Recurse -whatif
Remove-Item $sourcePath -Force -Recurse -WhatIf 
}
```

Source folder names are:

```
"D:\Test Source\33-FIT-1414"
"D:\Test Source\33-FIT-1576"
"D:\Test Source\33-FIT-1654A"
"D:\Test Source\33-fred-1234 unknown"
"D:\Test Source\33-FSL-1649"
"D:\Test Source\33-FV-1414"
"D:\Test Source\33-FV-1654"
"D:\Test Source\33-FV-1882"
"D:\Test Source\33-H-1657"
"D:\Test Source\33-H-1814"
"D:\Test Source\33-H-1924"
"D:\Test Source\asjhdsdlljhsdflj"
```

Destination folder names are:

```
"D:\Test Dest\33"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1108"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1111"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1120"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1125"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1130"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1135"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1209"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1223"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1252"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1254"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1307"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1309"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1317"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1351"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1414"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1426"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1428"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1432"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1433"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1434"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1435"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1451"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1476"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1526"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1528"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1532"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1533"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1554"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1565"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1576"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1623"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1626"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1649"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1654"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1659"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1671"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1709"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1712"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1799"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1800"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1801"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1882"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-1883"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-2000"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-2001"
"D:\Test Dest\33-F-2002"
"D:\Test Dest\33-ggg-1234"
"D:\Test Dest\1234"
"D:\Test Dest\daddybear"
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I would work on this line `$destinationDirectory\$matchesInBoth\$_` to be more like `$destinationDirectory\($matchesInBoth -match "$($sourcepath.split('-')[-1] -replace '[a-z]','')")\$_`

Comment: Also note it's easier when you do a foreach to either use `foreach ($item in $mathesinbith)` or to immediately set your variable so the $_ can't be broken accidentally. First line in foreach loop can be `$item = $_`. Then replace all your $_ with $item in the loop.

Comment: The code you posted is broken. Please do not wrap code in arbitrary places just to fit it to the width of the content area. If you're copy/pasting from a PowerShell console make sure to unwrap code that was auto-wrapped in that window.

Comment: Ansgar.  My apologies, I will edit the code to unwrap it.  It was late and I missed that when I copy/pasted.  

Robert, thank you for your input, I will give it a try later today when I have a minute, I have burnt up too many hours on this and need to get caught up on other tasks.  I will let you know how it goes and post the new code if I can get it to work.  Like I said, I'm a noob at powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite ambiguous,

- in the title you want copy,
- the text says move
- the code copies and deletes source instead of using `Move-Item`

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\10\18\SO_52866947.ps1
$SrcDir = "A:\Test\Source"
$DstDir = "A:\Test\Dest"

# Build hash table from Destination with 4digit key and Directory FullName as value
$DstHash = @{}
Get-ChildItem $DstDir -Directory | Where-Object Name -match '\d{4}'| ForEach-Object {
    $DstHash.$($Matches.Values)=$_.FullName
}

# Iterate source and check if destination key/value pair exists
Get-ChildItem $SrcDir -Directory | Where-Object Name -match '\d{4}'| ForEach-Object {
    if ($DstHash.ContainsKey($($Matches.Values))){
        "Move {0} to {1}" -f $_.FullName, $DstHash.$($Matches.Values)
        Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination $DstHash.$($Matches.Values) -Force
    } else {
        "no corresponding Destination found for: {0}" -f $_.FullName
    }
}
```

Sample output:
(with folders on my ramdrive A:)

```
> Q:\Test\2018\10\18\SO_52866947.ps1
Move A:\Test\Source\33-FIT-1414 to A:\Test\Dest\33-F-1414
Move A:\Test\Source\33-FIT-1576 to A:\Test\Dest\33-F-1576
Move A:\Test\Source\33-FIT-1654A to A:\Test\Dest\33-F-1654
Move A:\Test\Source\33-fred-1234 unknown to A:\Test\Dest\33-ggg-1234
Move A:\Test\Source\33-FSL-1649 to A:\Test\Dest\33-F-1649
Move A:\Test\Source\33-FV-1414 to A:\Test\Dest\33-F-1414
Move A:\Test\Source\33-FV-1654 to A:\Test\Dest\33-F-1654
Move A:\Test\Source\33-FV-1882 to A:\Test\Dest\33-F-1882
no corresponding Destination found for: A:\Test\Source\33-H-1657
no corresponding Destination found for: A:\Test\Source\33-H-1814
no corresponding Destination found for: A:\Test\Source\33-H-1924
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do.  Thank you so much for your help!  Really, you have no idea how much this helped me.